# Creating a symmetrical grid of random size squares in Python3/Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, math, tkinter

I have a question revolving around what would be a viable approach to placing out random-sized squares on a symmetrical, non-visible grid on a tkinter-canvas. I'm going to explain it quite thoroughly as it's a somewhat proprietary problem.

This far I've tried to solve it mostly mathematically. But I've found it to be quite a complex problem, and it seems reasonable that there would be a better approach to take it on than what I've tried.

In its most basic form the code looks like this:

```
while x_len > canvas_width:
                xpos = x_len + margin
                squares[i].place(x=xpos, y=ypos)
                x_len += square_size + space
                i += 1
```

x_len is the total width of all the squares on a given row, and resets when exiting the while-loop (eg. when x_len > window width), among with xpos (the position on X), as well as altering Y-axis to create a new row.

When placing same-size squares it looks like this:
[image: same-size squares]

So far so good.

However when the squares are of random-size it looks like this (at best):
[image: random-size squares]

The core problem, beyond that the layout can be quite unpredictable, is that the squares aren't centered to the "invisible grid" - because there is none.

So to solve this I've tried an approach where I use a fixed distance and a relative distance based on every given square. This yields satisficing results for the Y-axis on the first row, but not on the X-axis, nor the following rows on Y.

See example (where first row is centered on Y, but following rows and X is not):

[image: random-size squares with new function]

So with this method I'm using a per-square alteration in both Y- and X-axis, based on variables that I fetch from a list that contain widths for all of the generated squares.

In it's entirety it looks like this (though it's work in progress so it's not very well optimized):

```
square_widths = [60, 75, 75, 45...]

space = square_size*0.5
margin = (square_size+space)/2
xmax = frame_width - margin - square_size
xmin = -1 + margin

def iterate(ypos, xpos, x_len):
    y = ypos
    x = xpos
    z = x_len
    i=0
    m_ypos = 0
    extra_x = 0

    while len(squares) <= 100:
        n=-1
        # row_ypos alters y for every new row
        row_ypos += 200-square_widths[n]/2

        # this if-statement is not relevant to the question
        if x < 0:
            n=0
            xpos = x
            extra_x = x
            x_len = z
            while x_len < xmax:
                ypos = row_ypos
                extra_x += 100
                ypos = row_ypos + (200-square_widths[n])/2
                xpos = extra_x + (200-square_widths[n])/2
                squares[i].place(x=xpos, y=ypos)
                x_len = extra_x + 200
                i += 1
                n += 1
```

What's most relevant here is row_ypos, that alters Y for each row, as well as ypos, that alters Y for each square (I don't have a working calculation for X yet). What I would want to achieve is a similar result that I get for Y-axis on the first row; on all rows and columns (eg. both in X and Y). To create a symmetrical grid with squares of different sizes.

So my questions are:
Is this really best practice to solve this?
If so - Do you have any tips on decent calculations that would do the trick?
If not - How would you approach this?

A sidenote is that it has to be done "manually" and I can not use built-in functions of tkinter to solve it.

Comment: What exactly is in the "random sized squares"? Are you placing images in there? Text? Does it need to be a canvas? Have you tried simply calculating the height of the tallest object, and the width of your smallest object, and basing your grid off of that? Then, just center each item off of a simple multiple of that width and height.

Comment: It is of course arbitrary - an assignment in UI design (the content is a number). But I've been struggling with this for so long now it's time to give in with my stubbornness and ask for some directions. I think I have a version where I've tried that with no success - I do not exclude that I simply calculated it wrong. Say that the biggest object is 100px and the smallest is 30px, about how would that calculation look like?

Comment: Relevant to the point is that the center point of each square is the upper left corner, so I guess I have to do an adjustment based on the given square as well.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use the `grid` geometry manager?

```
COLUMNS = 5
ROWS = 5

for i in range(COLUMNS*ROWS):
    row, col = divmod(i, COLUMNS)
    l = tk.Label(self, text=i, font=('', randint(10,50)))
    l.grid(row=row, column=col)
```

This will line everything up, but the randomness may make the rows and columns different sizes. You can adjust that with the row- and columnconfigure functions:

```
import tkinter as tk
from random import randint

COLUMNS = 10
ROWS = 5
class GUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)

        labels = []
        for i in range(COLUMNS*ROWS):
            row, col = divmod(i, COLUMNS)
            l = tk.Label(self, text=i, font=('', randint(10,50)))
            l.grid(row=row, column=col)
            labels.append(l)

        self.update() # draw everything
        max_width = max(w.winfo_width() for w in labels)
        max_height = max(w.winfo_height() for w in labels)
        for column in range(self.grid_size()[0]):
            self.columnconfigure(col, minsize=max_width) # set all columns to the max width
        for row in range(self.grid_size()[1]):
            self.rowconfigure(row, minsize=max_height) # set all rows to the max height

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    win = GUI(root)
    win.pack()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I am sorry, I realize now that my post do not convey that I can't use the tkinter module. Eg. the backend is based on tkinter, but I can't use tkinter for the script I am working on. We're supposed to do it "the manual way". But as I take a personal interest in UI design I will look deeper into your solution for future applications! :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit that made the results not turn out the way expected, and it wasn't due to the calculations. Rather it turned out that the list I created didn't put the squares in correct order (which I should know since before).

And so I fetched the width from the raw data itself, which makes a lot more sense than creating a list.

The function now looks something like this (again, it's still under refinement, but I just wanted to post this, so that people don't waste their time in coming up with solutions to an already solved problem :)):

```
def iterate(ypos, xpos, x_len):
    y = ypos
    x = xpos
    z = x_len
    i=0

    while len(squares) <= 100:
        n=0
        if y > 1:
            ypos -= max1 + 10
        if y < 0:
            if ypos < 0:
                ypos=10
            else:
                ypos += max1 + 10 #+ (max1-min1)/2

        if x < 0:
            n=0
            xc=0
            xpos = x
            x_len = z

            while x_len < xmax:
                yc = ypos + (max1-squares[i].winfo_width())/2
                if xpos <= 0:
                    xpos = 10
                else:
                    xpos += max1 + 10
                xc = xpos + (max1-squares[i].winfo_width())/2
                squares[i].place(x=xc, y=yc)
                x_len += max1 + 10
                print (x_len)
                i += 1
                n += 1
```